# Can't change network scripts as noroot user?

Tags: linux, sudo, centos7

I am developing a java application that needs to change: ip, gateway, default route .... 
But this app doesn't have root permissions, executed with daemon user.

How do I set it so that the app can edit the files: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 and /etc/sysconfig/network ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the app with `sudo` to give it root permissions, or adjust the permissions of the 'daemon user' so that it can edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` and `/etc/sysconfig/network`.